# Array objects values remove unwanted string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following `originaldata`  which I would like to remove the div tags from the each objects inside it, leaving it with the content within the tags as the final result, see `modifieddata`.

What would be the best approach using javascript? filter and map? or something else.

```
originaldata = [{
        "name": "john",
        "content": "<div class="ExternalClass06EE5E42165840F48DFA193ACAD4F87A">aa</div>"
    },
    {
        "name": "mary",
        "content": "<div class="ExternalClass3D5F8061F3DE49C4BC55A9CE0ADD6F9A">asd</div>"
    }
]

modifieddata = [{
        "name": "john",
        "content": "aa"
    },
    {
      "name": "mary",
      "content": "asd"
    }
]
```

Comment: you have an error in the format. The string should be `'<div class="ExternalClass06EE5E42165840F48DFA193ACAD4F87A">aa</div>'` or "<div class=\"ExternalClass06EE5E42165840F48DFA193ACAD4F87A\">aa</div>"

Comment: @gurvinder372: It's not JSON anyway. But yes, it's still invalid.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder are you saying the accepted answer is incorrect? or not the correct way to solve the issue?

Comment: @DamienFlood: It's using a regex to parse HTML, which is not a good idea. The rest of it is fine if you want to take a functional approach (creating new objects).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder If there is additional HTML tags within the DIV would this also be removed. Ideally I would like to keep all the content within the DIV even if its other tags. Is this also possible?

Comment: @DamienFlood: I've updated the accepted answer to show how to do that (minor change).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks so much! This is great. Learned a lot using this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would be the best approach using javascript? filter and map? or something else.

If you want to take a functional approach, just `map` (copying the objects), you're not filtering.

If not, just `forEach` modifying the existing objects:

Here's the `map` version:

```js
var originaldata = [{
  "name": "john",
  "content": "<div class='ExternalClass06EE5E42165840F48DFA193ACAD4F87A'>aa</div>"
},
{
  "name": "mary",
  "content": "<div class='ExternalClass3D5F8061F3DE49C4BC55A9CE0ADD6F9A'>asd</div>"
}];
var temp = document.createElement("div");
var modifieddata = originaldata.map(entry => {
  temp.innerHTML = entry.content;
  return {
    name: entry.name,
    content: temp.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue
  };
});
console.log(modifieddata);
```

...or using a [Stage 3 proposal for object property spread](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) that browser vendors are actively adding (Chrome has it, for instance), we can avoid having to know the names of the other properties:

```js
// Note: I have the "Use BabelJS / ES2015" checkbox ticked
// so this will work even in browsers that don't
// have property spread yet.
const originaldata = [{
  "name": "john",
  "content": "<div class='ExternalClass06EE5E42165840F48DFA193ACAD4F87A'>aa</div>"
},
{
  "name": "mary",
  "content": "<div class='ExternalClass3D5F8061F3DE49C4BC55A9CE0ADD6F9A'>asd</div>"
}];
const temp = document.createElement("div");
const modifieddata = originaldata.map(entry => {
  temp.innerHTML = entry.content;
  return {
    ...entry, // <=== Property spread
    content: temp.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue
  };
});
console.log(modifieddata);
```

Here's the `forEach` version:

```js
var originaldata = [{
  "name": "john",
  "content": "<div class='ExternalClass06EE5E42165840F48DFA193ACAD4F87A'>aa</div>"
},
{
  "name": "mary",
  "content": "<div class='ExternalClass3D5F8061F3DE49C4BC55A9CE0ADD6F9A'>asd</div>"
}];
var temp = document.createElement("div");
originaldata.forEach(entry => {
  temp.innerHTML = entry.content;
  entry.content = temp.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue;
});
console.log(originaldata);
```

---

In a comment you've said:

> If there is additional HTML tags within the DIV would this also be removed. Ideally I would like to keep all the content within the DIV even if its other tags. Is this also possible?

In that case, in all of the above, change

```
entry.content = temp.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue;
```

to

```
entry.content = temp.firstChild.innerHTML;
```

Here's the `forEach` with that change:

```js
var originaldata = [{
  "name": "john",
  "content": "<div class='ExternalClass06EE5E42165840F48DFA193ACAD4F87A'>aa<span>stuff in a span</span><br></div>"
},
{
  "name": "mary",
  "content": "<div class='ExternalClass3D5F8061F3DE49C4BC55A9CE0ADD6F9A'>asd</div>"
}];
var temp = document.createElement("div");
originaldata.forEach(entry => {
  temp.innerHTML = entry.content;
  entry.content = temp.firstChild.innerHTML;
});
console.log(originaldata);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you must resolve the problem of quotes, you couldn't use the double quotes multiple time in the same string :

```
"<div class="ExternalClass06EE5E42165840F48DFA193ACAD4F87A">aa</div>"
^___________^_____________________________________________^_________^
```

Instead use single quotes :

```
 "<div class='ExternalClass06EE5E42165840F48DFA193ACAD4F87A '>aa</div>"
```

Then loop through the array and chnage the property you want :

```
for (var i in originaldata) {
   var temp_div = document.createElement('div'); //Create temporary div
   temp_div.innerHTML = originaldata[i].content; //Append the tag in the content to it

   originaldata[i].content = temp_div.textContent; //Get the text using 'textContent'
}
```

```js
var originaldata = [{
    "name": "john",
    "content": "<div class='ExternalClass06EE5E42165840F48DFA193ACAD4F87A '>aa</div>"
  },
  {
    "name": "mary",
    "content": "<div class='ExternalClass3D5F8061F3DE49C4BC55A9CE0ADD6F9A '>asd</div>"
  }
];

for (var i in originaldata) {
  var temp_div = document.createElement('div');
  temp_div.innerHTML = originaldata[i].content;

  originaldata[i].content = temp_div.textContent;
}

console.log(originaldata);
```

Comment: Pretty sure they don't want `"0"` and `"1"` in `content` (they've said they want `"aa"` and `"asd"`).

Comment: _"has no meaning & used just for example too"_ That would be a pretty specific "meaningless example"

Comment: He want's to remove the `<div>` tags and extract the text of them (stored in `content`). That step is missing in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` and `createElement`

```
var output = originaldata.map( function(item){
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = item.content;
  return { name : item.name, content : div.textContent }; 
});
```

```js
var originaldata = [{
"name": "john",
"content": "<div class= 'ExternalClass06EE5E42165840F48DFA193ACAD4F87A'>aa</div>"
},
{
"name": "mary",
"content": "<div class='ExternalClass3D5F8061F3DE49C4BC55A9CE0ADD6F9A'>asd</div>"
}];

var output = originaldata.map( function(item){
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = item.content;
  return { name : item.name, content : div.textContent }; 
});

console.log( output );
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and regexp:

```
const originaldata = [{
  "name": "john",
  "content": '<div class="ExternalClass06EE5E42165840F48DFA193ACAD4F87A">aa</div>'
},
{
  "name": "mary",
  "content": '<div class="ExternalClass3D5F8061F3DE49C4BC55A9CE0ADD6F9A">asd</div>'
}];

const regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;

const modifieddata = originaldata.map(item => ({ 
  name: item.name,
  content: item.content.replace(regex, "")
}));

console.log(modifieddata); // [{name: "john", content: "aa"}, {name: "mary", content: "asd"}]
```

**UPD.** If the structure of your contents could be more sophisticated than just one tag wrapper, then you should think about using another approach (for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47656609/3211932) and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47656357/3211932)).

Comment: [Have we learned nothing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454) ;-)

Comment: I don't see any HTML in the requirements)) PS love that post!

Comment: You're using a regex to parse HTML in your answer. Strongly suggest **not** doing that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder what approact you will follow then ?

Comment: In case of single tag-wrapper, I guess, this is appropriate solution. But I agree, in general the procedure should be another. I updated the answer.

Comment: @AL-zami: The one [in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47656357/157247) (also used -- independently -- by gurvinder372 in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47656444/157247)). Let the browser do it, they know how.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new *element* and then insert the *content* of the `originaldata` array to the newly created element.

Later on you retrieve the html of the element using `innerHTML` and overwrite the `original originaldata.content` with the `innerHTML`

**Working demo**

```js
var originaldata = [{
    "name": "john",
    "content": "<div class='ExternalClass06EE5E42165840F48DFA193ACAD4F87A '>aa</div>"
  },
  {
    "name": "mary",
    "content": "<div class='ExternalClass3D5F8061F3DE49C4BC55A9CE0ADD6F9A '>asd</div>"
  }
];

for (var i in originaldata) {
  var html = originaldata[i].content;
  var temp = document.createElement('div');
  
  temp.innerHTML = html;
   
  var htmlContent = temp.firstChild.innerHTML;
  
  originaldata[i].content = htmlContent;
}

console.log(originaldata)
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a one liner( assuming you will only have letters inside the div tag)

```
originaldata.forEach( x => { x.content = x.content.match(/>(\w+?)</)[1] })
```

arrays are reference type, so as object. So you can simply use forEach function to iterate over the array and use regex pattern `/>(\w+?)</` to match the content inside div tag.That will give you what you want.But be careful.It will change the original data source,in our case originaldata array.

Comment: It's incorrect to use `map` when you're A) Not returning anything from the callback, and B) Not using the return value. And of couse, [there's this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454).

Comment: Your were right.I shouldn't have used map.Changed it to to forEach.for A) it's not a pure function.I am not following a functional approact here.Then why it should matter whether i am returning something from the function or not ?

Comment: It mattered when using `map`. Doesn't matter now you're not using `map`. The HTML problem remains, and this answer really just duplicates previous answers in any case.